# Digit filter on tweets not working

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining

I'm trying to pull tweet floods from a user like 1. 2. etc. I took almost 1000 tweets, filter them starts with only digits but it doesn't give me all correct. It gives very small amount of tweets.

Here's some part of my code.

```
tot_tweet = userTimeline("bohringerstein", n=5000)

tweets_df = twListToDF(tot_tweet)
tweet_txt = tweets_df$text 

cleaned_txt <- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)","",tweet_txt)
cleaned_txt = gsub("@\\w+", "",cleaned_txt)
```

From here, everything is normal. When i do filtering it does not giving all tweets starts with any digits.

```
filtered <- grep(pattern = "^[1-150]", x= cleaned_txt, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Use `grep(pattern = "^\\d", x= cleaned_txt, value=TRUE)`.

Comment: thanks it's work. what is that //d for? and what if i want to filter any digits and a dot at the end.is it like "^\\d \\ .$?

Comment: \d stands for _any number_. The backslash has to be escaped in R by another one. Any number at the beginning and a dot at the end is ^\\d.*\\.$

Comment: Actually d has give me only digits but \\d+ gives all numbers. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. \\d is one digit, \\d+ is at least one digit